# Cordova run android keeps on failing

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle, androidx

I'm building my first cordova app and I'm trying to install it on my Android phone to check if everything is working.
But I keep getting the same error message over and over again:

C:\LesCordova\project_cordova>cordova build android

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Android-SDK (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Android-SDK
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
> The following AndroidX dependencies are detected: androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0, androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0, androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0, androidx.core
> :core:1.0.0, androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0, androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0, androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0, androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0, androidx.drawerlayout:drawerla
> yout:1.0.0, androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0, androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0, androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0, androidx.arch.core
> :core-common:2.0.0, androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0, androidx.lif
> ecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0, androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0, androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.
> 0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0, androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0, androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0, androidx.print:print:1.0.0

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
7 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 6 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\LesCordova\project_cordova\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\LesCordova\project_cordova\platforms\android\build.gradle

I already tried to change the android.useAndroidX property to true, but it changes back to false.
I already deleted the platform/android directory.

I realy hope someone knows what I'm doing wrong, because I'm running out of time...

Thank you!
Greetings Joyce